# Bundler + RVM + Passenger + Capistrano deployment & missing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, rvm, capistrano, bundler

I got the server with the configuration above.

This is the important part of my deploy.rb recipe:

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require 'rvm/capistrano'
require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.2-p290'
set :rvm_type, :system
set :bundle_flags, "--deployment"

set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => ENV['PATH'],
  'RAILS_ENV' => ENV['RAILS_ENV']
}

set :stages, %w(staging production)
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
```

Running `cap staging deploy` as is, leads to an error:

```
* executing "cd /mnt/data-store/project/releases/shared &&
bundle install --gemfile /mnt/data-store/project/releases/shared/Gemfile
--path /mnt/data-store/project/shared/bundle --deployment --without development test"

** [out :: localhost] The --deployment flag requires a Gemfile.lock.
Please make sure you have checked your Gemfile.lock into version control
before deploying.

... rolling back ...

failed: "env PATH=... RAILS_ENV=staging rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.2-p290' -c 'cd /mnt/data-store/project/releases/shared && bundle install --gemfile /mnt/data-store/project/releases/shared/Gemfile --path /mnt/data-store/project/shared/bundle --deployment --without development test'" on localhost
```

Gemfile and Gemfile.lock are in the source control. I ran `bundle install` locally first to generate the .lock file. But the bundler/capistrano points to /mnt/data-store/project/releases/shared/Gemfile so I just copied manually both files there. I'm sure I'm doing it wrong here. I guess it should be copied automatically.

Executed deploy again (1) and it didn't fail on the bundle install, it even had

`Your bundle is complete! It was installed into /mnt/data-store/project/shared/bundle` in the output.

BUT, one of my cap tasks executes a rake. The result of this is:
*Could not find bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 in any of the sources
*Try running `bundle install`.

Proceeding with my adventure, I discovered that once you have .bundle/config with
`BUNDLE_PATH: /mnt/data-store/project/shared/bundle`
It works.
I had this directory, probably created by bundler, under `/mnt/data-store/releases/shared/`, so I copied manually to the rails root.

Now, rake/rails c work.

`bundle show twitter` shows `.../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/twitter-1.7.1`.

BUT, redeploying brings me back to (1), because the .bundle dir isn't there.

Concrete questions:

1. Do I need to create/copy .bundle/config manually?
2. Do I need to copy Gemfile/Gemfile.lock manually to the shared dir? What happens if I add gems? Should I hold two copies, or manually/programmatically sync them?
3. WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this part in the deployment.rb file (Bundler code)

```
args = ["--gemfile #{File.join(context.fetch(:current_release), bundle_gemfile)}"]
args << "--path #{bundle_dir}" unless bundle_dir.to_s.empty?
```

There's a key called `:current_release`, this key is probably not being set correctly with Capistrano for some reason.

the `:current_release` in bundler will point to the "shared" folder instead of the latest release (with the timestamp)

This is getting executed on `before 'deploy:finalize_update'`.

What I would do in order to fix this is to add your own hook on this event.

```
before 'deploy:finalize_update', 'x:set_current_release'
```

And this is the actual method

```
task :set_current_release, :roles => :app do
    set :current_release, latest_release
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I still don't get why `current_release` points to the shared path instead of the actual release.

Answer (score 0):

Error

```
The --deployment flag requires a Gemfile.lock. Please make sure you have checked your Gemfile.lock into version control before deploying.
```

occurs when there is something unwantend inside your releases directory on server. There should be only directories with previous versions of your app (their names starts with date and looks like 20111025125442).

So, remove unwanted directories or files and then try to deploy again.